# What Intel CPUs are Goldmont microarchitecture?

Tags: cpu, microarchitecture

I need a machine for testing free and open source software under Intel's latest CPUs. Painting with a broad brush, the latest CPUs are 6th generation iCore processors.

As I understand things, the latest Intel CPUs have [Skylake microarchitecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skylake_(microarchitecture)). However, the instructions I am interested are supposedly from the [Goldmont microarchitecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldmont). Here is a [list of the instructions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_SHA_extensions) I need in the CPU:

- SHA1RNDS4
- SHA1NEXTE
- SHA1MSG1
- SHA1MSG2
- SHA256RNDS2
- SHA256MSG1
- SHA256MSG2

Please forgive my ignorance as I am not up on hardware like many folks. I can't really tell what I need to buy to get the [Goldmont microarchitecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldmont). Amazon returns lots of hits for *"Intel Skylake"*, but returns 0 hits for *"Intel Goldmont"*.

Can someone please state what CPUs are [Goldmont microarchitecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldmont)? For example, Core i3 6100, Core i5 6200 or Core i7 6700 are things I can easily understand, spec-out and purchase.

Comment: The Wikipedia article lists the CPUs that are based on this architecture worth pointing out they are Atom CPUs so the CPUs you have listed are NOT Atom CPUs

Comment: All of those instructions have been standard features in Intel CPUs for awhile now.  your not going to find System on Chip products on Amazon or Newegg.

Comment: Here are all the CPUs from intel's website: http://ark.intel.com/m/products/codename/80644/Apollo-Lake

Comment: Worth pointing out most of those CPUs have not been released just announced.

Comment: The Wikipedia article is incorrect, those instructions were NOT, introduced with Goldmount.  The article was edited back in September adding that single incorrect sentence, there is no reference to that statement, and I am finding documentation published by Intel from 2013 on those 4 SHA1 and 3 SHA256 instructions.  If you don't find my comments helpful, I will delete them, if you want

Comment: "A processor supports Intel SHA extensions if CPUID.(EAX=07H, ECX=0):EBX.SHA [bit 29] = 1. The SHA exten- sions require only XMM state support on operating systems, similar to SSE2 instructions." -Archive 2013 Intel programming manual